# Laravel env file is not loading

Tags: php, laravel, server, laravel-5.3, production-environment

I have moved my laravel project from local to production server which is centos vps.
Strange thing I'm facing is laravel can't read from .env file, And I have tested everything to make it work but no success.

I have set it's permission to 777 and it's owner to the owner of vps.

still no success.

FYI : it is in gitignore but I have created .env file on server so this problem has nothing to do with gitignore.

Can someone walk me through step by step running laravel on production server? 
Exactly what should be done and what commands do I need to execute, where should I put project and where should put public directory files ?

please help me out.

Comment: What are you trying to get from the `.env` file ? And what is the error saying ?

Comment: app_url, app-key, database configuration, cache configuration, lot's of data. I have put dd(env('APP_KEY')); in my code and it return null or ''

Comment: Might be wrong, but you have tried `php artisan config:clear`? Sounds like config:cache was maybe run and not realized :)

Comment: @Iskar yes I've tried that still no success

Comment: The permissions should never need to be 777. Did you run `composer install` on the server?

Comment: The reason Im asking is because you sholdnt be accessing .env from your controllers. Only from the config files. So, if you are trying to access it from your controller, I can show you a workaround. But if even your database cannot access it then you have to make sure the file is redable and not empty

Comment: No I didn't run composer install  on server , I've tried now and I've got putenv() has been disabled for security reasons error, I'm tring to remove it from php.ini

Comment: Ok now I've ran composer install and then I've tried to get the any value of env file but still no sucess and it's null

Comment: php artisan config:cache
 && php artisan config:clear

Comment: @Pedrammarandi I've done it still no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In production environments you should **never** have a .env file. Instead, create the appropriate environment variables and PHP will read them from there.

Taken from the official DotEnv docs:

> phpdotenv is made for development environments, and generally should
>   not be used in production. In production, the actual environment
>   variables should be set so that there is no overhead of loading the
>   .env file on each request. This can be achieved via an automated
>   deployment process with tools like Vagrant, chef, or Puppet, or can be
>   set manually with cloud hosts like Pagodabox and Heroku.

Comment: How can i accomplish this ? how to create environments variable instead of env ?

Comment: Thanks Man Solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could try to clear config cache:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this-

**Copied from the official Documentation**

After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions. Directories within the  storage and the bootstrap/cache directories should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run. If you are using the Homestead virtual machine, these permissions should already be set.

Comment: My storage directory permission is 777 and is writable by server owner, but problem still is there.

Comment: You may try installing laravel using softaculous installer and then copy all your views, models, controllers and routes to the corresponding directory.