# Laravel 4 is not reading env file

Tags: laravel, homestead

At first, this is not duplicate. I've already tried the next and any of them worked:

- [Laravel 5.2 not reading env file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420761/laravel-5-2-not-reading-env-file)
- [Laravel 5.2 is not reading from .env on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377914/laravel-5-2-is-not-reading-from-env-on-ubuntu)
- [Laravel env file is not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42111490/laravel-env-file-is-not-loading)
- [Laravel 4 with forge, environment variables issue](https://laravel.io/forum/08-22-2014-laravel-4-with-forge-environment-variables-issue)

I'm using Mac and Homestead on Virtual Box to virtualize Laravel 4.

What I did:

1. Download the project from the repository
2. composer install and composer dump-autoload within vm
3. set up env file
4. set up homestead.yaml and /etc/hosts
5. vagrant halt / vagrant up --provision

This is the error:
https://i.gyazo.com/77effc81c4b99b40d1b8b3c0b41d9f6d.png (I'm not allowed to add images blablabla...)

So I decided to remove and create env file again. I checked my version of php, environment and hostname and all of them are right...

If you need further information just let me know. Thanks for everyone in advance.

EDIT: Obviously I tried every solution suggested in the previous Stackoverflow questions posted.

Comment: env('PP_API_ENDPOINT') tried ?

Comment: it shows the same error

Comment: env func doesn't show index undefined error it just returns null or the default value passed as second argument.

Comment: I think the variable want to access to the value but it can't find it so it shows undefined index, isn't it?

Comment: see in the pic you are trying to access the value from global array `$_ENV` if the array doesn't have a value with this key i.e `PP_API_ENDPOINT` it will show error. but when you use this helper function `env('key','default')` it returns null if the value is not found or there is no second argument otherwise return the value.

Comment: The issue is because env file has that key and a value but for some reason, that variable cannot access it.

Comment: `var_dump($_ENV)` and see if other values are there or not.

Comment: it doesn't work because the page doesn't load

Comment: page doesn't load means?

Comment: it means I can't see the content of the website because the error appears earlier.

Comment: you can use `dd($_ENV)` helper function for that.

Comment: Place it before breaking code.

Comment: /home/vagrant/Code/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:513:
array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: Is .env file placed in project folder ? Make sure you have placed it there and is in proper format.

Comment: It is in the main folder named .env.local.php because is working on Laravel 4

Comment: and your environment is set to local ?

Comment: yes, it is. I already checked it

Comment: make `.env.php` file and copy  the content of `.env.local.php` in that file then check it. you can also check if these both files are loading by simply using `exit` keyword before return statement if application loads with blank page then your file is loading properly

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. It was some shit about env file and PhpStorm. I removed the env file and created again with sublime text, wrote manually all keys and values and it worked!!!

Thank you for Shahzaib Sheikh help.